# glob.glob returns same order in each iteration?

Tags: python, glob

Does glob.glob returns the files in same order in every iteration?

If I run this: 
`import glob from glob` 
`files = glob(path)`

Will the order of files be always same or may change in different iterations?

Comment: well, `files` is a list, so the iteration order will always be the same, but I don't think it is guaranteed that `glob` will return a list in the same order on each invocation of the program.

Comment: The first sentence of the documentation says that names are returned in an arbitrary order. I don't see anything that guarantees that the order will always be the same. (That said, I *suspect* that as long as result doesn't *change*, the order won't arbitrarily change. But add or remove one file from the result, and the order could be different.)

Comment: If you care about a repeatable order, sort it by whatever criteria you want.